# python celery not working

Tags: python, celery

I'm new to celery and python in general and wanted to use celery to have an async task in the application.
While I tried to see how it works, a demo app itself was not working on my local setup.
**I started rabbitmq server locally on the system with default config: user: guest, password: guest and on default port 5672.**

I picked the sample code from http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/hello')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

All these were done and are placed inside of a virtualenv. Then I am in the folder location containing the app.py file and use the command:
**celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info** to run the celery worker from the terminal.
Getting following output after executing the command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 13, in main
    from celery.bin.celery import main as _main
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .base import Option
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from celery import VERSION_BANNER, Celery, maybe_patch_concurrency
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 509, in __getattr__
    module = __import__(self._object_origins[name], None, None, [name])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/app/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from celery import _state
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/_state.py", line 15, in <module>
    from celery.utils.threads import LocalStack
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .functional import memoize  # noqa
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/functional.py", line 11, in <module>
    from kombu.utils.functional import (
ImportError: cannot import name LRUCache
```

Dependencies used: 
**amqp 2.2.2, billiard 3.5.0.3, celery 4.1.0, kombu 4.1.0, python 3.6**

Let me know the mistake and if any other details required

Answer (score 1):

The current command to run your celery worker will be:

```
celery -A app worker --loglevel=info
```

Provided your worker file is called **app.py**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost:5672/')
```

Also (even if I don't think it's related to you error) you're saying that you use python 3.6 but on error trace it look like it is version 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the dev version of Billiard and Kombu:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/celery/billiard.git#egg=billiard
pip install -e git+https://github.com/celery/kombu.git#egg=kombu
```